# How to read potentiometer value in existing circuit

Tags: potentiometer

I built a circuit for heater controller and it works fine.

I want to read poentiometer R3 values with microcontroller Arduino. I am not sure if I am doing correct way, but I connected Arduino analog pin to potentiometer wiper pin and Arduino GND to circuit GND (heater circuit and microcontroler have separate power sources.) I got values in range 500-1000, but somewhere in  between of pot turning values drops to 20-40.

I know that we can read potentiometer values when we connect side pins to power and wiper pin to microcontroller analog pin.  But how can I read the potentiometer when the wiper is already connected to +5V?

I am using the following code:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}

`enter code here`

[image]

Comment: What is the part number for the 8 pin part?

Comment: voltage on arduino A0 input could be as high as 5V.  Can your input handle that?  Perhaps your arduino has a limit of 3.3V and you're frying the input?

Comment: Incidentally, [Using pot as variable resistor: should wiper be connected to spare end terminal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/246823/36731)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your circuit is using a 555 timer. These work by charging up C via R1 + R2 + R3 until the trigger threshold is reached (about 2/3 supply) and then the DIScharge pin is pulled low. This causes C to discharge through DIS and R1 until THReshold reaches about 1/3 supply at which point DIScharge is switched off and the cycle can repeat.

Your scheme won't work well because the voltage at the junction of R2 - R3 is oscillating. Instead, you can monitor the 555 output and do some timing measurements.

The big question: why are you using a 555 when you have a micro-controller? Feed the potentiometer into an analog input and control the output duty cycle with that instead. You may need a transistor to switch the relay but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use the ADC on an oscillating value, you could time the relay on and off times, and then calculate the pot value.

\$ R_3 = \frac{T_{ON} - T_{OFF}}{T_{ON}}\cdot R_1 - R_2 \$